# Activiti: Check Process Failed to Ended

Tags: java, activiti

I am trying to find a way to check on a process if ended successfully or failed and all retrials were done (async activities)

I am using History level AUDIT

The following code run OK if the process ended without any errors, but in case of errors, it don't work:

```
ProcessInstanceQuery processInstanceRS = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(pId);
ProcessInstance instance = processInstanceRS.singleResult();
if (instance == null)
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, there is a table called ACT_RU_DEADLETTER_JOB, if the job was retried and failed, a record for the job will be moved there, Activiti has API to query this table and also to reset the retry counter to resume the job again